# Drill Down (Highcharts) not working with dynamic data in Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I'm using high chart API in my angular project, my issue is when I get dynamic data I successfully generate highchart but when I click on any state my drilldown function not getting hit or not working. It's required in my scenario to use highchart with drilldown so after around 5 hours of searching and development, I don't get any solution yet not from google or highcharts own forum.

Here is my code:

```
generateMap() {
this.Highcharts = Highcharts;

const usMapData = require("@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json");
const usMap = Highcharts.geojson(usMapData);

this.chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    height: (8 / 16) * 100 + "%",
  },
  events: {
    drilldown: function (e) {
      this.methodMap(e.point.splitName);
      const chart = this as any;
      const mapKey = "countries/us/" + e.point.drilldown + "-all";
      const mapData = require(`@highcharts/map-collection/${mapKey}.geo.json`);
      const provinceData = Highcharts.geojson(mapData);

      chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
        name: e.point.name,
        data: provinceData,

        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.name}'
        }
      });

      chart.setTitle(null, { text: e.point.name });
    },
    drillup() {
      const chart = this as any;
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ""
  },
  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: "#E6E7E8",
    maxColor: "#417BCC"
  },

  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: "bottom"
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    map: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          color: "#F8BA03"
        }
      }
    },
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function (e) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      animation: {
        duration: 1000
      },
      name: "United States",
      data: null,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        format: `{point.splitName}`,
        style: {
          textTransform: 'uppercase',
        }
      },
    }
  ],
  drilldown: {}
};

this.CurrentVendorService.getAllVendorStates().pipe(
  tap(result => {
    this.chart.showLoading();
    
    usMap.forEach((el: any, i) => {
      el.splitName = el.properties["hc-key"].split('-')[1].toUpperCase();
      el.drilldown = el.properties["hc-key"];
      const getFirstMatchedVendor = result.data.find(vendorObj => vendorObj.State_Code == el.splitName);
      if (getFirstMatchedVendor) {
        el.value = getFirstMatchedVendor.Vendor_Count;
      }
    });
    
    this.chartOptions.series = [
      {
        data: usMap
      }
    ];
    
    this.updateFromInput = true;
    this.chart.hideLoading();
  },
    (error: any) => {
      this.gifLoader = false
      this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
      this.snackBar.open(this.errorMessage, '', {
        duration: 2000,
      });
      console.log(`error on retriving all vendors state list : ${error}`);
    }
  ),
  finalize(() => {})).subscribe();
}
```

Component.Html

```
<highcharts-chart
          [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
          [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
          [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
          [options]="chartOptions"
          style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
          [(update)]="updateFromInput"
        ></highcharts-chart>
```

`generateMap()` call in `ngOnInit()`. If I use static data instead of service. Its works like a charm but that's not the case here. I need to work drilldown with my dynamic data. Please help me with this what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of struggling found my own question-answer.
I'm still learning and improving my attention to detail on my programming problems.

**Solution**

Let me spoon feed you, so you just copy-paste it and get it done.

Some globally declarations:

```
Highcharts;
chartConstructor = "mapChart";
chartOptions: Highcharts.Options;
updateFromInput = false;
chart;
chartCallback;
```

Put the below code snippet in your component constructor

```
this.chartCallback = chart => {
    this.chart = chart;
};
```

Put below code in `ngOnInit()`

```
this.generateMap();
```

Now the main part:

```
generateMap() {
    const self = this;
    self.Highcharts = Highcharts;

    const usMapData = require("@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json");
    const usMap = Highcharts.geojson(usMapData);

    self.chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            height: (8 / 16) * 100 + "%",
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e: any) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        self.methodMap(e.point.splitName);
                        const mapKey = "countries/us/" + e.point.drilldown + "-all";
                        const mapData = require(`@highcharts/map-collection/${mapKey}.geo.json`);
                        const provinceData = Highcharts.geojson(mapData);
                        self.chart.hideLoading();
                        self.chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
                            name: e.point.name,
                            data: provinceData,

                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{point.name}'
                            }
                        } as Highcharts.SeriesOptionsType);

                        self.chart.setTitle(null, { text: e.point.name });
                    }, 100);
                },
                drillup() {
                    self.resetMethod();
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: "#E6E7E8",
            maxColor: "#417BCC"
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: "bottom"
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            map: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: "#F8BA03"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: "map",
                name: "United States",
                data: null,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    format: `{point.splitName}`,
                    style: {
                        textTransform: 'uppercase',
                    }
                },
            }
        ],
        drilldown: {}
    };

    self.CurrentVendorService.getAllVendorStates().pipe(
        tap(result => {
            self.chart.showLoading();

            usMap.forEach((el: any, i) => {
                el.splitName = el.properties["hc-key"].split('-')[1].toUpperCase();
                el.drilldown = el.properties["hc-key"];
                const getFirstMatchedVendor = result.data.find(vendorObj => vendorObj.State_Code == el.splitName);
                if (getFirstMatchedVendor) {
                    el.value = getFirstMatchedVendor.Vendor_Count;
                }
            });

            self.chartOptions.series = [
                {
                    type: "map",
                    data: usMap
                }
            ];

            self.updateFromInput = true;
            self.chart.hideLoading();
        },
            (error: any) => {
                self.gifLoader = false
                self.errorMessage = error.error.message;
                self.snackBar.open(self.errorMessage, '', {
                    duration: 2000,
                });
                console.log(`error on retriving all vendors state list : ${error}`);
            }
        ),
        finalize(() => { })).subscribe();
}
```

Yes, you will customize the above business logic as per your need. But that's what I want. I've done some modifications in `self.chartOptions` object and add `setTimeout`.

**Cheers!**